# Should I mirror account creation when people SSO with different providers?

Tags: architecture, openid-connect, keycloak

**edit**

***It seems that keycloack provide SSO with google and lot more. So I ended-up using only keycloack and not letting him implementing google***

This question is a bit general and it doesn't involve any specific language. And sorry if that question seems a bit stupid.

I'm trying to build some API services with openid connect protocol,so in this case that means I need only to authorise my user for the API access (and they will check if the token_access is valid).

But for that, they must be authentified first from other layers like in the frontend. I will use Keycloack for that.

My question is: when people SSO with Google, Twitter, etc... for the first time. Should I mirror a user with their email adress as field (who are unique by design) in keycloak too in order to give them the token generated by keycloak. The APIs will in their turn ask keycloak service to introspect the token and check if it's in the scope and that the token is valid.

I'm kind of lost here because that means that I will need to create some accounts without a password field. Those who will create account with keycloak will use their own password, but those from google and twitter can't for obvious security reason. Of course, I can generate one based on the email footprint. But is it a good pratice?

I don't see any other solution for that. In the same time, I don't know how I can let a user access to my API endpoint without that "hack", even if they will indirectly use it via a frontend interface. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you asking whether you should create a new Keycloak user and token for clients using a third party OAuth provider (Google and such) for authentication or to use the original third party token for accessing your API services (so the API would accept both - Keycloak and third party tokens)?

Comment: Yeah I did. I just figured out with a little research that keycloak implements its own. So I removed my client part.

Comment: Yeah I did. I just figured out with a little research that keycloak implements its own. So I removed my client part.